# DataGridView custom column header content (checkbox control)

Tags: winforms, datagridview, customization

Is it possible to add functionality "check all" to WinForms *DataGridView*'s *DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn*?

It should look like the following:

[image]

Click on highlited checkbox should check/uncheck all checkboxes in the grid.

As I can see, column header can contain only string values. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final implementation is mostly solution, proposed by Samir in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42437/Toggling-the-States-of-all-CheckBoxes-Inside-a-Dat) article.

But it requires fix of checkbox position when grid horizontal scrollbar is moving. So here follows methods that needed to be changed:

```
private void frmSelectAll_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddHeaderCheckBox();

    HeaderCheckBox.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(HeaderCheckBox_KeyUp);
    HeaderCheckBox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(HeaderCheckBox_MouseClick);
    dgvSelectAll.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvSelectAll_CellValueChanged);
    dgvSelectAll.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dgvSelectAll_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
    dgvSelectAll.CellPainting += new DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(dgvSelectAll_CellPainting);

    BindGridView();

    var checkboxHeaderCellRect = dgvSelectAll.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, false);
    headerCheckboxRightMargin = (checkboxHeaderCellRect.Width - HeaderCheckBox.Width)/2;
}

private int headerCheckboxRightMargin;

private void ResetHeaderCheckBoxLocation(int ColumnIndex, int RowIndex)
{
    //Get the column header cell bounds
    Rectangle oRectangle = this.dgvSelectAll.GetCellDisplayRectangle(ColumnIndex, RowIndex, false);

    Point oPoint = new Point();

    oPoint.X = oRectangle.Location.X + (oRectangle.Width - headerCheckboxRightMargin - HeaderCheckBox.Width);
    oPoint.Y = oRectangle.Location.Y + (oRectangle.Height - HeaderCheckBox.Height) / 2 + 1;

    if (oPoint.X < oRectangle.X)
    {
        HeaderCheckBox.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        HeaderCheckBox.Visible = true;
    }

    //Change the location of the CheckBox to make it stay on the header
    HeaderCheckBox.Location = oPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2008/11/17/c-add-select-all-deselect-all-checkbox-in-column-header-in-datagridview-control/

Comment: Thank you. But that post doesn't work well with scrolling grid horizontally. I've found another one, based on your link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42437/Toggling-the-States-of-all-CheckBoxes-Inside-a-Dat. Though it required fixing as well