# Anchor Button to DataGridView Column Header so it resizes correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to attach buttons to Header Columns within a DataGrid so the buttons will move with the Header Column when the DataGrid resizes.  Columns are set in Properties to Fill.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 - Windows Form Designer.

The problem is I'm not sure how to anchor the buttons to the columns so they move with specific columns when the DataGrid is resized.  The example pictures are based on the buttons being anchored as Left-Top.

The following links show example pictures as follows:

Example 1 - shows the **buttons** on the ColumnHeader **before** resizing larger (inserted button and dragged and dropped on ColumnHeader):

[image]

Example 2 - shows the **buttons** on the ColumnHeader **after** resizing larger:

[image]

Comment: Can you show related `xaml`? And possible some better explanation (screenshot?) of what means "move differently" (but it may become clear after you post `xaml`).

Comment: Thanks for the response - I am actually using windows-forms-designer in VS2013 not WPF.  I just setup an account and don't have enough reps to post a picture.  I can email you some pics if you could email me at marcbailey@bizdatasolution.com.   Thanks

Comment: I am alone might not be able to solve your issue but community may do. Please use public services to share pictures (google for `share picture`) and put links to them into question. How do you attach buttons? In code behind? Show that code please.

Comment: Sinatr - thanks for the suggestion - I have edited my original post to include the links and clarity.  The buttons are not actually attached to the DataGrid they were inserted on top of the DataGrid.  I would like to attach selected buttons to specific columns in the DataGrid.

Comment: The demand is unusual. I could think of 2 possibilities: 1) handle layout (move buttons as datagridview horizontally scrolled or columns are resized) 2) custom column header. Try to see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12642348/1997232) helps ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22561664/1997232) is similar to yours question I think).

Comment: Thanks I will review these.